# clearCache of flutter_webview_plugin package doesn't work

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I use the WebView_plugin in my Flutter project. I can load my own website. But my website updates aren't there. I guess it's a cache issue.

I tried to pass some options like: `clearCache`, `appCacheEnabled` but my website updates aren't there.

How I instantiate my webview:

```
dart 
    final webView = WebviewScaffold(
      url: url,
      clearCache: true, // <-- I don't want cache 
      appCacheEnabled: false, // <-- I don't want cache
      initialChild: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: const Center(
          child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
      withZoom: false,
      withLocalStorage: true,
      hidden: true,
    );
```

In my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.5
```

How do I clear the cache?

Answer (score 1):

try it, frist `clearCache: true` and after `appcacheEnable: false`

```
    dart 
        final webView = WebviewScaffold(      
          clearCache: true, // <-- first clearCache
          appCacheEnabled: false, // <--after it :3
          url: url,
          initialChild: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: const Center(
              child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          ),
          withZoom: false,
          withLocalStorage: true,
          hidden: true,
        );
```

Comment: This really can't be right based on how named params work, can it?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is, add a random generated number as parameter in url.

Like this:

```
class WebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  WebView(this.url);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final randNum = Random().nextInt(1000);
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My Web"),
      ),
      url: "$url?id=$randNum",
      hidden: true,
      initialChild: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```